# Prevent scrolling when in portrait mode android

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollview

I have an xml which uses linear layout and weights to equally distribute space on the screen to a few buttons and such. When I rotate screen to landscape mode, the buttons all get compressed. Could someone tell me how to make the buttons take equal space, non scrollable, when in portrait, and the whole screen scrollable when in landscape. Presently I am not using any scrollview and the layout is looking good, with the table and buttons taking the right amount of space, but when i rotate the screen to landscape, everything gets compressed. I tried enclosing the Linear Layout inside a scrollview but that caused the Linear Layout to move out of the screen, so when in portrait mode, i have to scroll to see whole content. Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#bf000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtReceive1"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:background="#fff3f3f2"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="CH"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:padding="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="kWh"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Load"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Date"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow >
            <TextView
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/t11"
                android:text="1" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t12" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t13" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t14" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t21"
                android:text="2" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t22" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t23" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t24" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t31"
                android:text="3" />
            <TextView

                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t32" />
            <TextView

                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t34" />
        </TableRow> <TableRow>
        <TextView

            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t41"
            android:text="4" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t42" />
        <TextView

            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t43" />
        <TextView

            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t44" />
    </TableRow>
        <TableRow >
            <TextView
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/t51"
                android:text="5" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"

                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t52" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"

                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t53" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/t54" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff8c00"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:id="@+id/txtReceive"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:id="@+id/rel">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_01_small"
                    android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Channel"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_02"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="kWh"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="000.0"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_03"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Load"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="000"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_04_small" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Days"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="000"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive"
            android:id="@+id/rel2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_01_small"
                    android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Auto ON"
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton12"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                    android:id="@+id/textView92"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton12"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton22"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_04_small"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"/>





            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Auto OFF"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:id="@+id/textView62"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton22"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="#ffa5ff45"
                android:id="@+id/textView102"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton22"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


        </RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton31"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send_btn_01"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:text="SET TIME" />
        </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton32"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/send_btn_01"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:text="RECHARGE" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/base_irya_left1"
    android:background="#bf000000"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
```

Comment: Two xmls, one for landscape and one for portrait, are your best bet. Portrait goes into `res/layout` folder and landscape goes into `res/layout-land`.

Comment: @Matter Cat, thanks for the idea, I will try to implement.

Comment: @MatterCat thank you so much, I did what you suggested and it worked. How can I mark your comment as the right answer? By the way now i am facing another problem.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070889/scrollview-not-scrolling-and-application-restart-on-orientation-change

Comment: Moved comment to answer, and it looks like someone got to your other question already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating two xmls, one for landscape and one for portrait, will fix the issue. Portrait goes into `res/layout` folder and landscape goes into `res/layout-land`. The two should have identical names for this to work.

Comment: this comment is amazing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider using Fragments in Android. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) is a tutorial.

**How to support different screensizes with fragments**(See [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html))

It is possible to define in the layout file of an activity that it contains fragments (static definition) or to modify the fragments of an activity at runtime (dynamic definition).

To display differnet fragments in your activities based on the actual available space you can:

Use one activity, which displays two fragments for tablets and on handset devices. In this case change at runtime the fragments displayed by the activity whenever necessary. In this scenario you typically define instances of the FrameLayout class as placeholder in your layout and add the fragments at runtime to them.

Use separate activities to host each fragment on a handset. For example, when the tablet UI uses two fragments in an activity, use the same activity for handsets, but supply an alternative layout that includes just one fragment. If the detailed fragment is there, the main activity tells the fragment that it should update itself. If the detail fragment is not available, the main activity starts the detailed activity.

Which option to select depends on the use case, typical the dynamic contribution is more flexible bit a bit harder to implement.

Comment: Will using Fragments make much difference

Comment: @user3705704 I have edited my answer, I hope that helps